# Метод POST не работает, метод GET работает (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, post

Работаю на ларавел 9.
Создаю в файле web первый способ через:

```
Route::get('cabinet/send-all-messages/send', [EmployerController::class, 'send_all_post'])->name('send_all_post');
```

такой способ отправки данных работает.

Если меняю метод на POST, то не работает

```
Route::post('cabinet/send-all-messages/send', [EmployerController::class, 'send_all_post'])->name('send_all_post');
```

Форма POST-метод.

```
   <form class="cabinet__body" action="{{ route('employer.send_all_post') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     ...
   </form>
```

В чем может быть причина? Это баг или что-то упускаю? Раньше такой ошибки не было.

Comment: У Вас в форме указан метод method="GET"

Comment: Нет было POST, но и с таким методом не работало.

Comment: А не работает, это как? Так-то понятие довольно широкое) Возвращает ошибку, что в консоли, какой ответ от сервера и тп.

Comment: @Simon, ошибка 404, когда по факту роут есть, а на самом деле переход выдает ошибку 404.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что необходимо сделать после изменений в web.php - это снова "закешировать" маршруты.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

В остальном, должно работать.
Если не работает, то нужно смотреть на конкретную ошибку, которую выбрасывает Laravel.

Если для отправки постов используются (передаются) какие-то данные, то вероятно, что ошибка может возникнуть на уровне валидации запроса.
Для более конкретного ответа нужен код контролера и код Request (если используется специализированный Request).

Попробуйте сделать route:cache, скорее всего поможет в вашем случае.

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку  Unable to prepare route [admin/password] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [admin.password].

Comment: По команде route:list только один роут с таким адресом.

Comment: Ошибка 404 бывает, когда отсутствует роут данный.